# How to determine a PL/SQL function's schema from within the function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL package in an Oracle 10g database and I want to write a function that returns the name of the schema that the package (and hence the function) is defined in.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
create function xcurr return varchar2 is
  v_curr varchar2(32);
begin
  SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') into v_curr from dual;
  return v_curr;
end;
```

This will work as long as the PL/SQL object doesn't have AUTHID CURRENT_USER.

Comment: Wow.  I knew about that, but expected it to return the current user, not the user that the function was running as.  Thanks!

Comment: In current versions of Oracle database, you can call `SYS_CONTEXT()` directly from PL/SQL to avoid the [expensive and unnecessary context switch](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/09/07/beware-of-hidden-pl-sql-to-sql-context-switches/).

Answer (score 7):

From Oracle 10g [CURRENT_USER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm#CIHEFDFI), as used in [Gary Myers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1035652/458741), is deprecated. Oracle recommends that you use the SESSION_USER parameter instead, which:

> For enterprises users, returns the schema. For other users, returns
>   the database user name by which the current user is authenticated.
>   This value remains the same throughout the duration of the session.

I would use CURRENT_SCHEMA. There are subtle differences between the two as CURRENT_SCHEMA changes if an `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA` statement is issued.

There's also no need to SELECT from dual; you can assign the return value of SYS_CONTEXT directly to the variable.

```
DECLARE
    v_current_schema varchar2(30);
BEGIN
    v_current_schema := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA');
    dbms_output.put_line('I am using the schema [' || v_current_schema || ']');
END;
```

Comment: It isn't much different, but there are a few distinct reasons I don't like the other answer. 1. You don't need to select from dual into a variable, just assign it. 2. CURRENT_USER is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm). 3. There are minor yet distinct differences between CURRENT_SCHEMA and SESSION_USER.

Comment: Fair enough @Tom. I wasn't aware. I've updated your answer to reflect all of this. Please take a look and see if there's anything you'd like to change.

Comment: It appears that this deprecation was lifted in later versions of Oracle, [as the meaning has been repurposed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html#GUID-B9934A5D-D97B-4E51-B01B-80C76A5BD086)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an easier way but you could use `dbms_utility.format_call_stack` and parse the results to get the schema name. This works in Oracle 9i.